# Adding SequenceTypes not implemented in Swift's standard library

Tags: swift, operator-overloading, standard-library, swift2

In the standard library of Swift the `+` operator is only overloaded with `ExtensibleCollectionType` and another type which definitely conforms to `SequenceType`:

```
func + <C : ExtensibleCollectionType, S : CollectionType where S.Generator.Element == C.Generator.Element>(lhs: C, rhs: S) -> C
func + <C : ExtensibleCollectionType, S : SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == C.Generator.Element>(lhs: C, rhs: S) -> C
func + <C : ExtensibleCollectionType, S : SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == C.Generator.Element>(lhs: S, rhs: C) -> C
func + <EC1 : ExtensibleCollectionType, EC2 : ExtensibleCollectionType where EC1.Generator.Element == EC2.Generator.Element>(lhs: EC1, rhs: EC2) -> EC1
```

So why don't they overload it also with `SequenceTypes` or at least `CollectionTypes` since they can easily be added as an `Array`?:

```
func + <S1: SequenceType, S2: SequenceType where S1.Generator.Element == S2.Generator.Element>(s1: S1, s2: S2) -> [S1.Generator.Element] {
    return Array(s1) + Array(s2)
}
```

Are there any benefits don't implementing this overload?

Answer (score 1):

But that would always convert your collection to an Array which may not be intended.

By restricting the lhs to an extensible collection type, the same type can be used as return value. This way, no conversion takes place implicitly and the addition could be implemented more efficiently.

If you do not care for the conversion to an Array, you can always do that explicitly: `Array(lhs) + rhs`.