# Dictionary doesn't conform to ExtensibleCollectionType

Tags: swift, dictionary, standard-library, swift2, swift-protocols

Dictionaries in Swift don't conform to `ExtensibleCollectionType`. Since it would be easy to extend it (it somehow doesn't work with Swift 1.2; using Swift 2):

```
extension Dictionary: ExtensibleCollectionType {

    // ignoring this function
    mutating public func reserveCapacity(n: Int) {}

    mutating public func append(x: Dictionary.Generator.Element) {
        self[x.0] = x.1
    }

    mutating public func extend<S : SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == Dictionary.Generator.Element>(newElements: S) {
        for x in newElements {
            self.append(x)
        }
    }
}
```

If you do so Dictionaries can also be added (see also: [Adding SequenceTypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31140092/adding-sequencetypes-not-implemented-in-swifts-standard-library))

Is there any benefit don't implementing this in the standard library?

Comment: I see no harmful consequences of doing so. You should file a bug report.

Comment: The bug in Swift 1.2 (was solved in Swift 2) or a suggestion for implementing this in the standard library?

Comment: A suggestion for implementing this.

Comment: the semantics are wrong, Dictionaries are not ordered lists, so 'append' is not meaningful (nor is 'extend')

Comment: Why is "append" not meaningful for unordered lists?

Comment: Perhaps the 'ordered' vs 'unordered' distinction is not relevant here - though in any case I wouldn't consider a Dictionary a 'list' of any sort, it is more correctly an unordered collection of key-value pairs. As such, it doesn't make sense to 'append' something to it, to "attach something to the end" (?) of a Dictionary. If you were able to 'append' something to a particular collection, you'd expect to be able to ask for the last element in that collection and get back the item you just appended, right? Can you do that with a Dictionary?  ;)

Comment: Ok "append" is probably not the "right" expression for a unordered collection. But at least "extend" should be implemented by Dictionary since something (information) can be added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Xcode 7 beta 5 `ExtensibleCollectionType` was renamed (and restructured) to `RangeReplaceableCollectionType`. So the intention conforming to this protocol is more clear:

The new protocol only requires this method to fully conform to it:

```
mutating func replaceRange<C : CollectionType where C.Generator.Element == Generator.Element>(subRange: Range<Self.Index>, with newElements: C)
```

This wouldn't make much sense for any unordered collections since this operation isn't predictable (except for the element count in some cases). Also the default implementations and other requirements which highly rely on the index aren't that useful for such collections.

In conclusion insertions and replacements of ranges should be predictable and preserve the structure/ordering of the other elements. Therefore `Dictionaries` and any other unordered collection shouldn't conform to this particular protocol.